# What are the consequence to communication if a species can speak and listen at the same time?

Tags: aliens

My aliens have evolved so that they can simultaneously speak and listen.  At the very least, they don't have to wait for a reply before starting to talk, and they can be speaking to person A while listening to person B.  What are the differences between their communication and ours?  How does "dialog" work, if at all?

Comment: What's the actual question specifically, if it's the title of the question then can you define what's meant by "full duplex" (I have a feeling that's a North American expression, not all readers will be familiar with it) - if it's in the body of the question can you please be specific, in addition you could amend the title to reflect the actual question. That all being said "dialogue" in what context? Conflict - people shout over each-other, intimate moments off enthusiasm - people talk over each other? How many brains do your aliens possess (each)? Voting to close 'till you [edit].

Comment: The issue with being able to listen and speak at the same time is that to reply to a person, you must first know what they are saying. You cannot answer a question part way through, because your assumption of the end may be completely wrong. So unless you can address this issue, your conversation is more like a person having a monologue while also listening to other people monologue.

Comment: @Hoyle'sghost, it's a computer communications term.  Full duplex is like a telephone, where people can listen and talk at the same time.  Half duplex is like a walkie-talkie, where one person listens while the other speaks, then "over" and they change roles.  Simplex is like a radio broadcast, one-way only.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'd like to be certain that the OP means the same thing and that the question is edited to reflect this. The meaning may be familiar to you and many others, but the question is the place for definitions, not the comments. Bicameral brains are different from simple neural networks, question needs better defining.

Comment: The aliens can simultaneously speak and listen is what I meant. I am not sure how to clarify further

Comment: It is also possible for humans to speak and listen at the same time. If you want to make it even easier, put some sound proof headphones on a person and feed them the noise directly so there is no interference with their voice.

Comment: I VTC because it wasn't a fully fledged question IMHO.  Go check out people using sign language.  Because you can move your hands while still looking at the other person, you can both talk at the same time.  You can also talk at the same time on a text view screen (the old fashioned split ones, with the command "talk" in a UNIX shell).  Unlike with speech, there's no interference.  Just your ability to multitask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your alien design fails to take into account the very reason for language to exist in the first place - the efficient exchange of information.

The human brain receives a deluge of sensory input constantly. We can close our eyes to be sure, but even when typing this I can still feel the keys of the keyboard, hear the clatter of their strikes against the contact plate, hear a few distracting conversations and other people typing in the background. Yet, I can still put together a (hopefully) cogent argument and articulate it in text.

This is even worse in places like coffee shops and bars where there is a lot of background noise, including other conversations, yet we tend to hold down our own localised conversations with little difficulty.

I've even watched a group arguing where they're each talking over each other, but they're also listening - they're using the others' arguments against them while still in full flight shouting out their own case.

So, I'd argue, that if put to the test *we* are an example of a species that can go 'full duplex' if we have to. So, why don't we?

There are two reasons. The first is convention. Talking over the top of someone is considered impolite and we're trained not to do it, to listen to a single person at a time and allow each person to articulate their own views in relative quiet. That certainly aids concentration on what that person has to say, and it also ensures a respectful reception for your own views in turn.

The second reason is that exchange of information implies cause and effect. Many of the ideas we discuss now are complex and may take a relatively long time to express in words, and may require some concentration on our part to understand, especially if the person talking expresses himself in informationally dense language, like jargon.

Our whole model of logic is based on the idea of cause and effect; a set of rules that work in one temporal direction and don't always work in the other. That means, we are psychologically programmed to want to know the complete picture before we start reasoning on it. We can't do that in full duplex, because we'd only be responding on the part of the picture already articulated. For us at least, that seems impulsive and leads to errors of logic because we may well be missing critical details that are to be expressed later in the first person's missive.

Your aliens, if they don't have the same social mores or structures of logic are actually limiting themselves to simplistic reasoning models which by definition will limit their ability to abstract out details and patterns, and identify technological improvements that can be made in their society. When you get right down to it, language works not because of one's capacity to speak, but one's capacity to listen.

Another way of putting this idea is that the transfer of information benefits the recipient more than it benefits the messenger. Why put the energy into sharing one's information if one thinks that only parts of it will be understood or received? In such a situation, there's no real reason to speak at all. There's no benefit to the group from such sharing, meaning there's no benefit to the person sharing.

Remember, language is about coordination of effort, and bringing the next generation up to speed with the lessons learned to date faster meaning they can build on what is known, not spend their lives learning the same lessons. Writing is so powerful because it accelerates that model again, allowing people to share knowledge with far MORE people than verbal speech can, before mass recording in any event. As such, going full duplex kind of misses the point, which is why we don't do it ourselves.

Of more practical benefit would be the ability to listen to multiple parallel streams of information, like two or more conversations at once. If you could multitask information input, that would be far more useful and productive for your society of aliens than being able to listen to a single conversation and talk at the same time.

Comment: `cause and effect` +1.  Unless two unique and fundamentally conversations are occurring (the one you're listening to and the one they're listening to), the need to stop one's train of thought and change directions is far too common for full-duplex to make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

**I can't top Tim B II's answer**

So go vote for it.  But I'd like to add a little real-life insight.

The closest I've ever seen to "full-duplex" communication was during a period of my life when I lived in Finland.  The native speakers (especially the older speakers) had the most unique and frustrating ability you may ever see.

They speak ***both*** on the exhale *and on the inhale.*

Is this full-duplex speaking?  Nope.  *It's full-time speaking.*  And while they're doing it, others will interject into the conversation (close to full-duplex.  Call it "three-quarter-duplex" for fun).

*If you're not used to it, it's exhausting.*  Just to *listen* to it is exhausting.

As a native English speaker, I'm conditioned (that's important: *conditioned*) to pauses in conversation.  Commas, periods, they're turn to speak vs. my own, etc.  There's a ton of "white space" in the conversation where my (our?) mind has a chance to evaluate what's being said and decide where to go next with the conversation.

But when two of those Finnish folks go at it in both breathing directions... It's absolutely *amazing,* and nearly impossible to keep up with.

**Conclusion**

Full-duplex communication is certainly fast and obviously efficient — if the nature of the conversation permits information exchange at that speed.  We humans, for the most part, are not *conditioned* to exchange information that quickly.

And if you think about it, why should we?  What does anyone have to say (other than gossiping about what useless celebrity trivia they just heard on *Entertainment Tonight*) that needs that much compression?

*Life is short, even your aliens might want to slow down and smell the roses.  I'm just sayin'*

Answer (score 1):

Information must still move linearly. The only way it makes sense for Alien Alice to start taking before Alien Bob finishes is to carry a concurrent conversation. Bob and Alice can literally have two different and unrelated conversations at once, say the weather and that curious human problem. At best, Bob can continue on to his second point while Alice starts her reply to Bob's first point.

The only difference is that Alice and Bob need stronger etiquette cues. Surely, neither like being interrupted for the same reasons humans don't. It frustrates effective communication.

A few ways Alice and Bob can indicate they've finished a thought:

1. Literally express it.

   *"Hey, nice weather we're having? End thought. How about those humans, huh? End thought."*
2. Literally express it with nuanced vocabulary. This could be fun because you get to invent words. Inflection can add levels of complexity.
   *"Hey, nice weather we're having, quancuni. How about those humans, quicha?"*
   You may have not realized it, but English already has a few words that indicate desired response type, like "huh" with that casual inflection.
3. Sign language. Exact movements of the hands and fingers can give the cues perfectly, and fit as a third communication level.
   *"Hey, nice weather we're having. [Lifts left hand to the ear] How about those humans, huh? [makes ok-sign]"*
   For extra fun, the concurrent conversation can be entirely done in sign.
4. Peculiar behavioral cues that we'd normally call body language and facial expressions. This is the perfect solution if you want their communication to be mysterious. Instead of giving the reader the dialog, you'd summarize it.
   *Alice suggested the weather with that pleading expression that asks for action, presumably, cutting the lawn, and immediately followed with the concerned flick of the eyebrows while asking what ought to be done with the humans.*

By point four you can see that we've left the stage for world building and entered the chapter on writing. That's not my forte and it's off topic anyway, but I suggest that you be careful with this and really only use it if you need it as a plot device, otherwise  your alien characters effectively cannot have dialog your audience can enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

- As mentioned by other replies for N=2 persons this wouldn't really change a lot of things since you still have to wait for the person to finish their sentence to be able to reply.
- For N>2 this opens up a lot of possibilities. Imagine a group of 20 person all talking to each other simultaneously. 
  To be able to do that, the brainpower needed would be significantly higher than ours. Your alien species would be very "talkative", super social and super smart. Imagine how efficient things like these would be:Corporate meetings, political discussions, research, brain storming etc...